# Why am I getting undefined method error ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
require "rubygems"
require "json"
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("https://api.website.com/top/inside/end")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
http.use_ssl = true
response = http.request(request)

if response.code == "200"
  result = JSON.parse(response.body)
  names = Array.new
  i = 0
  result.each do |doc|
    names.insert(i, doc.name)
    puts doc["id"] #reference properties like this
    puts doc # this is the result in object form    
    puts ""
    puts ""

  end

  puts names
else
  puts "ERROR!!!"
end
```

Why am I getting undefined method error on variable names inside the for each loop? I cannot understand why

> script.rb:18:in `block in ': undefined method `name' for #<Hash:0x0000000002e04c08> (NoMethodError)

Comment: Do you mean doc['name']?

Comment: Its hash so you Sould call it `names.push(i,doc["name"])`

Answer (score 2):

line 18,

```
names.insert(i, doc.name)
```

doc is a Hash, `doc['name']` should works.

in javascript, you can do

```
doc.name
```